# Pointwise convergence of $n\sin(x/n)$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\{f_n\}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n\sin(x/n) = x$. Does this mean that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise for all $x$? But if $x=0$, then is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n\sin(0/n)=0$ valid? Or am I confusing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It means. If $x=0$, then you have the sequence $0, 0, 0, ...$ which evidently converges to $0$. Thus $f_n$ converges pointwise for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x=0$ then $n\sin(\frac{x}{n})=n\sin(0)=0$.